# Best way to prevent value getting change

Tags: php, ajax, security, pdo, null

I am creating an e-commerce website some of you might find it usual. Basely I have for an example shoes starting from size 8-13 but each of those sizes have different price. I used a jquery to change the price based on what shoe size the user choose.

When a user clicks on add to cart the shoe size is posted to the cart page and from that I use the query below to find the price based on the price.

**Query to find the price based on the selected shoe size**

```
SELECT Product.Name as ProductName, Category.Name, size, Price
FROM Itemised_Product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.ProdID =:item_id
AND size= :size AND Category.Name = :Category Limit  1");
```

**Issue**
Because of security reason that why I use the select size to find price but the problem is that someone could use java script injection to change the value of the size to 0 and then they add to cart... nothing will show but the cart table will still appear like

```
Name                  Category                   Shoes type                 Price







                                                          Total price: $ 0.00
```

**Summary**
Basically Is they a way when the user change the value that nothing will show on the cart table. Or a way that even though the value is change that the right value is posted to the cart page?

Thanks

Comment: why can't you just check the query result if it returned anything? With one simple `if` operator?

Comment: It is totally irrelevant what is shown in the card if the user manipulated the view. As long as you can make absolutely sure that you do not further process any of the values that might have been manipulated. Don't try to fix something someone else broke by purpose!

Comment: @arkascha so you saying I shouldn't worry about someone changing value because that is their own issue?

Answer (score -1):

What about to check the value (size) before adding to cart?

Procedure before adding to cart:

```
SELECT size
FROM Itemised_Product, Product
WHERE Product.ProdID =:item_id
```

-> save it to array (or some object) -> check whether size received from customer is in that array

```
if(in_array($_POST('size'), $array_of_sizes))
{ 
    //add to cart
}
```

Comment: so are you saying That below when I have post the values I should run a query to change if the right size has been posted?

Comment: Because these values stored in database, not array?

Comment: @Your Common Sense do U mean am I posting the values to a database? if so. the answer is `no`